# rails jquery popup if user not logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

trying to have a simple box popup if a user has been on site for certain duration (3 seconds for testing) and they're not logged in.

It works fine, but it's still popping up even when a user is logged in, and that shouldn't be case.

the HAML:

```
.signuppopup{:id => if current_user then "user_id#{current_user.id}" else "user_id#{0}" end}
  %h1 You've been browsing the site for a while, why not sign up?
```

the coffescript:

```
signupPopUp = ->
  $(".signuppopup").css "display", "block" unless $("#user_id").val() is 0
  return
setTimeout signupPopUp, 3000
```

When I console.log the $("#user_id").val() it always says it's undefined even when I'm logged in

the css (not the issue):

```
.signuppopup{
  opacity:0.92;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  background: #69EAB8;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `haml` code for setting the `:id` is not correct; so it is not being set, and hence `$("#user_id").val()` is evaluating to undefined in all cases.

Try:

haml:

```
.signuppopup{:id => (if current_user then "signed_in" else "not_signed_in")}
  %h1 You've been browsing the site for a while, why not sign up?
```

coffeescript:

```
signupPopUp = ->
  $(".signuppopup").css "display", "block"  if $("#signed_in").length > 0
  return

setTimeout signupPopUp, 3000
```

Comment: thank you! this worked except a few minor changes, first simplifying the HAML to 

.signuppopup{:id => (unless current_user then "not_signed_in" end)}

and then the coffee needs to be 

if $("#not_signed_in").length > 0

Comment: Glad to help :-) Right, it should have been `unless $("#signed_in").length > 0` in my answer.